# Vuetify 3 Custom Icon Sets

Tags: vuetify.js, vuejs3

I'm trying to use boxicons in vuetify 3 and got lost following the official documentation [here](https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/features/icon-fonts/#creating-a-custom-icon-set). Would anyone help with understanding the documentation or at least provide a working example of how to implement custom icon sets apart from the ones that are already included with vuetify.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a solution?